# background image command defined in header not working

Tags: css

I have been scratchingmy head about why the background image function is not working for me. Any suggestions? Yes I already know that Im a dumbass with severe attention problems..

```
<head> 
<style type="text/css"> 


<!-- As you can see below, i tried to include a header image in 3 different ways -->

header {height:200px; background-url:(http://i.imgur.com/HtAvI.jpg) ; }
#header-wrapper { width:660px; margin:0 auto 10px; border:1px solid $bordercolor; background:url(http://i.imgur.com/HtAvI.jpg) no-repeat; height:400px; }
#header{background image: url(http://i.imgur.com/HtAvI.jpg);}

<!-- i tried including it in the body as well, to no avail -->
body { background image: url(http://i.imgur.com/HtAvI.jpg) ; }
p {color: red}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>this is text</p>

</body>"
```

Comment: Change `background image:` to `background-image:`

Comment: publish it as an asnwer... ;)

Comment: and you don't have any id="header-wrapper" and id="header" HTML elements, nor any header element (that does not exist).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `background image:` to `background-image:`. Also there is no property like `background-url`

Answer (score 0):

There is no `background-url`. There is no `background<space>image`. There is `background-image` and there is `background`.

Once you fix those problems the images should display correctly.